# Systemd LimitNOFILE capped to 4096

Tags: systemd, ulimit, systemd-user

I have a systemd user service with `LimitNOFILE` set. The value is respected until it hits 4096. After that point, it's capped to 4096. I've also tried increasing `DefaultLimitNOFILE` in `/etc/systemd/user.conf`.

It's set correctly in limits.conf, which works for new shells out of the box. Though, I heard systemd doesn't care about that file. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 11):

Late answer; 
`limits.conf` is not used when systemd is running (`limits.conf` is for non-systemd systems).

The file you actually want is; `/etc/systemd/system.conf` - this is the global config.  Then you have `/etc/systemd/user.conf` - this specifies further per-user restrictions.

Specifically in your case; even though you have configured `user.conf` with a higher limit, this is not valid as the limit in `system.conf` is lower, and acts as a cap on the limit in `user.conf`

O_O

Answer (score 2):

From `man systemd.exec`:

> For system units these resource limits may be chosen freely. For user units however (i.e. units run by a per-user instance of systemd(1)), these limits are bound by (possibly more restrictive) per-user limits enforced by the OS.

Your system probably has a configured hard limit of 4096 open files per process. It would open up a loophole if systemd allowed you to bypass this limit.

Comment: Thanks for the man page reference. I'm not sure that's quite it since I have `limits.conf` configured, but it should get me further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to systemd prior to version 240:

See: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/NEWS

> CHANGES WITH 240:
> ...
>
> - The Linux kernel's current default RLIMIT_NOFILE resource limit for
>   userspace processes is set to 1024 (soft) and 4096
>   (hard). **Previously, systemd passed this on unmodified to all
>   processes it forked off**. With this systemd release the hard limit
>   systemd passes on is increased to 512K, overriding the kernel's
>   defaults and substantially increasing the number of simultaneous file
>   descriptors unprivileged userspace processes can allocate ...

So try to upgrade your systemd to version 240 or later